# How do you get search params from Page route (not API route) in Next.js v13.4+?

Tags: next.js, next.js13

Doing this used to be done like this:

````
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

export default function TacoPage() {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { taco } = router.query; 

``` but this no longer works.
````

Answer (score 0):

You now use a read-only version of the Web API standard URLSearchParams.  This is provided now by Next.js like this:

```
'use client'
 
import { useSearchParams } from 'next/navigation'
 
export default function TacoPage() {
  const searchParams = useSearchParams()
 
  const taco = searchParams.get('taco')
 
  // URL -> `/cool?taco=my-taco`
  // `taco` -> 'my-taco'
  return <>Taco: {taco}</>
}
```

These are the other read-only methods of URLSearchParams:

- get()
- getAll()
- keys()
- values()
- entries()
- forEach()
- toString()

---

Note - `useSearchParams` is a Client Component hook and is not supported in Server Components (so only available on Client Pages or Client Components) ... this prevents having stale values during partial rendering.  Full explanation [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-search-params#layouts) and [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/layout#layouts-do-not-receive-searchparams).

But on server pages, you can get parameter values like this:

```
export default function Page({
  searchParams
})
```

which returns something like this in these cases:

```
URL searchParams
/cool?a=1   { a: '1' }
/cool?a=1&b=2   { a: '1', b: '2' }
/cool?a=1&a=2   { a: ['1', '2'] }
```

[Docs here](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/page)

> searchParams is a Dynamic API whose values cannot be known ahead of
> time. Using it will opt the page into dynamic rendering at request
> time. searchParams returns a plain JavaScript object.

So you can still get the query parameters like this:

```
const { a, b } = searchParams;
```

... and no need to worry if the  query parameter value does not exist as they will not error out they will only be `undefined`.

---

From the Next.js docs [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-search-params).

And here is the [standard](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#urlsearchparams) on which it is based.

Here is the MSN [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) on the topic.